# Adding videos to Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are developing a game about driving awareness.

The problem is we need to show videos to the user if he makes any mistakes after completing driving. For example, if he makes two mistakes we need to show two videos at the end of the game.

Can you help with this. I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

@solus already gave you an answer, regarding "how to play a (pre-registered) video from your application". However, from what I've understood, you are asking about saving (and visualize) a kind of replay for the "wrong" actions, performed by the player. This is not an easy task, and I don't think that you can receive an exaustive answer, but only some advices. I will try to give you my own ones.

First of all, you should **"capture" the position of the player's car, in various time periods**.
As an example, you could read player's car position every 0.2 seconds, and save it into a structure (example: a List).

Then, you would implement some logic to **detect the "wrong" actions** (crashes, speeding...They obviously depend on your game) and **save a reference** to the pair ["mistake", "relevant portion of the list containg car's positions for that event"].

Now, you have all what you need to **recreate a replay of the action**: that is, making the car "driving alone", by reading the previously saved positions (that will act as waypoints for generating the route).

Obviously, you also have to deal with the camera's position and rotation: just leave it attached to the car (as the normal "in-game" action), or modify it during time to catch the more interesting angulations, as the AAA racing games do (this will make the overall task more difficult, of course).

Comment: There are a couple of options from the Asset Store: [EZ Replay Manager](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3584) and [InputVCR](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3071).

Comment: @solus: Right, I've forgotten to mention them. BTW, the former consist in a limited version, for the free distribution (the complete version costs about 80$, I think). Didn't know about the latter, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unity will import a video as a [`MovieTexture`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MovieTexture.html). It will be converted to the native Theora/Vorbis (Ogg) format. (Use [ffmpeg2theora](http://v2v.cc/~j/ffmpeg2theora/examples.html) if import fails.)

Simply apply it as you would any texture. You could use a plane or a flat cube. You should adjust its `localScale` to the aspect ratio of your video (`movie.width/(float)movie.height`).

Put the attached audioclip in an `AudioSource`. Then call `movie.Play()` and `audio.Play()`.

You could also load the video from a local file path or the web (in the correct format).

```
var movie = new WWW(@"file://C:\videos\myvideo.ogv").movie;

...

if(movie.isReadyToPlay)
{
    renderer.material.mainTexture = movie;
    audio.clip = movie.audioClip;
    movie.Play();
    audio.clip.Play();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I think that the OP asked about "How to create a replay for a particular in-game action", that differs from "reading a pre-registered video". I added my own answer, regarding that, hoping to have understood the question correctly.

Comment: @BiG Yeah, that would make more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Use MovieTexture, but do not forget to install QuickTime, you need it to [import movie clip](http://druss.co/2015/05/unity3d-how-to-play-video-in-unity-project-movietexture/) (.mov file for example).